# Why Null Reference is given for System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices() when called from unity3d plugin dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, winapi, service, system

I'm trying to implement **ServiceController** which is part of Windows API to check state of a Windows Service from a c# dll plugin in Unity3d. When I run the dll from Unity Editor the result is given properly as weather the service is present or not. But when I make a build and try to run as a exe it gives the following error:

```
  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at (wrapper unknown) System.ServiceProcess.Win32ServiceController/ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS:PtrToStructure (intptr,object)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal:PtrToStructure (intptr,System.Type)
  at System.ServiceProcess.Win32ServiceController.GetServices (System.String machineName, SERVICE_TYPE serviceType, System.String group) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceProcess.Win32ServiceController.GetServices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices (System.String machineName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is the static method in dll which I'm calling from Unity3d code:

```
public static bool isServicePresent(string serviceName)
{
    bool serviceExists = false;
    foreach (ServiceController sc in ServiceController.GetServices())
    {
        if (sc.ServiceName == serviceName)
        {
            //service is found
            serviceExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return serviceExists;
}
```

Although the error comes from the part **GetService()** but if I try with function mentioned below the error wont be generated for standalone and editor. I do know for the fact that it might have something to do with **new** keyword but I'm totally not confirmed.

```
public static int GetServiceControllerStatus(string serviceName)
{

    try
    {
        if(serviceController == null)
            serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        //return "Invalid service name."; // Note that just because a name is valid does not mean the service exists.
        return 0;
    }

    using (serviceController)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceController.Refresh(); // calling sc.Refresh() is unnecessary on the first use of `Status` but if you keep the ServiceController in-memory then be sure to call this if you're using it periodically.
            return (int)serviceController.Status;
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ex)
        {
            // A Win32Exception will be raised if the service-name does not exist or the running process has insufficient permissions to query service status.
            // See Win32 QueryServiceStatus()'s documentation.
            //return "Error: " + ex.Message;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

So regarding above outcome I have few questions:

- Why is it working in Unity Editor and not in standalone build?
- If working in UnityEditor means does unityeditor has something which it
  initialised or extra dll dependancy which my standalone doesn't have?
- So if I want to use GetServices() in Unity3d standalone how would I make it work?
- I also used the **sc.DependentServices** where sc is created from **new ServiceController();** and according to the [description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.dependentservices(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) it says "Gets the set of services that depends on the service associated with this ServiceController instance." But when I tested it did not retrieved my desired service. So using this does not guarantee it will return all sets of services on the pc?

I don't have any experience regarding working with windows API. Any help regarding this I would really appreciate.

Comment: I belive that this is security issue. Your process must have **SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS** access right to invoke `QueryServiceStatus` winapi function.

Comment: @vasily.sib Pardon me but I'm unaware of  SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS &   even on static function like **ServiceController.GetServices()**  it requires this SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS? If that is the case then how does **GetServiceControllerStatus** function works without SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS?

Comment: `ServiceController.GetServices()` and others are actually just a thin wrappers around native unmanaged win32 api calls like `QueryServiceStatus`, `OpenService`, `OpenSCManager` and others. I point **SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS** as just one posible reason why this all happens. You can try to wrap `ServiceController.GetServices()` call in try-catch and get `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` as soon as posible right after exception is thrown - this (hopefully) will give you actual error code.

Comment: `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` gives me value as 0 in try catch block which implies that there is no win32error. So its something like `new ServiceController()` has to be initialised before using `ServiceController.GetServices()`. Iam calling `ServiceController.GetServices()` very first and not afterwards.

Comment: The problem with `GetLastWin32Error` is that it returns _Last_ Win32Error. 0 - is **ERROR_OK** Win32Error, which means, that either there was no Win32Error, or that there is a successfull WinAPI call right after some Win32Error:)

Comment: if calling `new ServiceController()` before `ServiceController.GetServices()` is fixing the issue, I think you can use it as a solution. Not the best solution, but will go.

Comment: It was supposed to be question, I forgot to type question mark at the end though. 
"So its something like `new ServiceController()` has to be initialised before using `ServiceController.GetServices()`?" 
Either way I tried just now with initializing but the null reference doesn't seem to stop coming. I wonder if there is something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Appears it only works when you set player settings to use .NET4.x (in my version anyway) instead of the .NET Standard 2.0.